# Search for multiple files by name and copy to a new folder

Tags: python, input, copy, directory

I have been trying to write some python code in order to get each line from a .txt file and search for a file with that name in a folder and its subfolders. After this I want to copy that file in a preset destination folder.

The thing is when I test this code I can read all the files in the .txt and I can display all files in a directory and its subdirectories. The problem rises when I have to compare the filename I read from the .txt (line by line as I said) with all the filenames within the directory folder and then copy the file there.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

```
import os, shutil

def main():

dst = '/Users/jorjis/Desktop/new'

f = open('/Users/jorjis/Desktop/articles.txt', 'rb')
lines = [line[:-1] for line in f]
for files in os.walk("/Users/jorjis/Desktop/folder/"):
    for line in lines:
        if line == files:
            shutil.copy('/dir/file.ext', '/new/dir')
```

Comment: Do the lines in the `.txt` contain the entire path or are they just `some_name.txt`?

Comment: The .txt file looks like this (where each name is under the others...they are not in the same line I mean):
14060873.json
10961282.json
11038869.json
...
So it contains just the name of the file, not its path!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the file names from the text file with a tuple with three elements: the root path of the currently visited folder, a list of all subdirectory names in that path, and a list of all file names in that path.  Comparing a string with a tuple will *never* be true.  You have to compare each file name with the set of file names to copy.  The data type `set` comes in handy here.

Opening a file together with the `with` statement ensures that it is closed when the control flow leaves the `with` block.

The code might look like this:

```
import os
import shutil

def main():
    destination = '/Users/jorjis/Desktop/new'

    with open('/Users/jorjis/Desktop/articles.txt', 'r') as lines:
        filenames_to_copy = set(line.rstrip() for line in lines)

    for root, _, filenames in os.walk('/Users/jorjis/Desktop/folder/'):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename in filenames_to_copy:
                shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, filename), destination)
```

Comment: Thanks mate! The only problem I have is using the shutil.copy() but I will check closer the documentation. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I would say that the files in the `.txt`  contain the entire path. You'd need to add a little more to `os.walk` to match up completely.

```
for root, _, files in os.walk("/Users/jorjis/Desktop/folder/"):
    for f in files:
        new_path = f + root
        if new_path in lines:
            shutil.copy(new_path, `/some_new_dir')
```

Then again, I'm not sure what the `.txt` file looks like so it might be that your original way works. If that's the case, take a closer look at the `lines = ...` line.

Comment: The .txt file looks like this (where each name is under the others...they are not in the same line I mean):
14060873.json
10961282.json
11038869.json
...
I can't just provide another path to the folder the files have to be copied to? I mean is it better to "calculate" the path like that?
Thanks mate !